# set up Hadoop multi cluster on 2 windows 10

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set up a multi-node Hadoop cluster between 2 windows devices. I am using Hadoop 2.9.2.
how can I achieve that, please.

Comment: What kind of windows are you using?

Comment: windows 10 home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install open-ssh server on both of your systems using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse). Generating a new SSH public and private key pair on your local computer is the first step towards authenticating with a remote server without a password. Add the public key to the authorized_keys and add your hostname to list of known hosts. You can find guides on how to do this by searching the internet.
   2.Add your hadoop master and slave ips to your hosts file. Open “C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts”
   and add

```
your-master-ip hadoopMaster
your-salve-ip hadoopSlave
```

you can use these names in your configuration files.

much like Linux systems, these are the steps you have to follow in order to run a Hadoop cluster on windows:
3. First you need to have Java installed on your system and JAVA_HOME must be added to your environment variables. You can download Java from [Oracle website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) and install it.

4. Download Hadoop binary files from [Apache website](https://hadoop.apache.org/release/2.9.2.html) and extract it.
5. Note that you shouldn't have space in your folder names or you might encounter problems.
6. Next you have to add Java and Hadoop home and bin folders to your environment variables. just open start menu and type "environment variable" and open the edit environment variables window from control panel.
7. Add

```
HADOOP_HOME=”root of your hadoop extracted folder\hadoop-2.9.2″
HADOOP_BIN=”root of hadoop extracted folder\hadoop-2.9.2\bin”
JAVA_HOME=<Root of your JDK installation>”
```

8. Edit your "path" environment variable and add %JAVA_HOME%, %HADOOP_HOME%, %HADOOP_BIN%, %HADOOP_HOME%/sbin to your PATH one by one.
9. you can validate your additions by opening cmd and type in:

```
echo %HADOOP_HOME%
echo %HADOOP_BIN%
echo %PATH%
```

CONFIGURING HADOOP:
10. Open "your hadoop root\hadoop-2.9.2\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd" and add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
set HADOOP_PREFIX=%HADOOP_HOME%
set HADOOP_CONF_DIR=%HADOOP_PREFIX%\etc\hadoop
set YARN_CONF_DIR=%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%
set PATH=%PATH%;%HADOOP_PREFIX%\bin
```

11.Open "your-hadoop-root\hadoop-2.9.2\etc\hadoop\hdfs-site.xml" and add the below content:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>your desired address</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>your desired address</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.permissions</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
<value>hadoopMaster:50070</value>
<description>Your NameNode hostname for http access.</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
<value>hadoopMaster:50090</value>
<description>Your Secondary NameNode hostname for http access.</description>
</property>
```

12. edit your core-site.xml and add:

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://hadoopMaster:9000</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.permissions</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>your-temp-directory</value>
<description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
```

13. Open "root to hadoop\hadoop-2.9.2\etc\hadoop\mapred-site.xml" and add below content within   tags. If you don’t see mapred-site.xml then open mapred-site.xml.template file and rename it to mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>hadoopMaster:9001</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

14.Edit your yarn-site.xml and add:

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce.shuffle</value>
<description>Long running service which executes on Node Manager(s) and provides MapReduce Sort and Shuffle functionality.</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
<value>true</value>
<description>Enable log aggregation so application logs are moved onto hdfs and are viewable via web ui after the application completed. The default location on hdfs is '/log' and can be changed via yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir property</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>hadoopMaster:8030</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>hadoopMaster:8031</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>hadoopMaster:8032</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
<value>hadoopMaster:8033</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>hadoopMaster:8088</value>
</property>
```

15. In your slaves file in "root-hadoop-directory/hadoop/bin" add

```
hadoopSlave
```

16. Do these steps on your slave nodes too.
17. open cmd and cd to your sbin folder in hadoop directory.
    18.format your nameNode

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

19.run the following command:

```
start-dfs.sh
```

20. then run:

```
start-yarn.sh
```

Comment: when starting "start-dfs.sh" it askes for password i put the slave node login password but i get Hassan@slave's password: slave: Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: Did you add your slave system to your known hosts? you can do that by using "ssh hadoopSlave" command. I also recommend to run your cmd as admin.

Comment: yeah i can ssh from master to slave and vice versa. the thing is, master node user is hassan@master
slave node user is hadoop@slave. but when running start-dfs.sh it asks for hassan@slave and i dont know where that user came from
but when running

Comment: instead of start-dfs.sh, I used start-all.cmd in master and slave nodes the answer below shows more details.

Answer (score 2):

after a lot of trial and error the following did the job me.

1. do same configuration as previous answer by @AbsoluteBeginner.
2. disable windows firewall on all machines (i think you could keep it on and just mess around with the rules, but thats for you to find out)
3. hdfs namenode -format all nodes (master and slaves)
4. make sure that the datanode folder is empty in all 3 nodes (just shift+del)
5. in master node run start-all.cmd. all the following should appear.
   50436 NameNode
   54696 NodeManager
   54744 DataNode
   60028 Jps
   7340 ResourceManager
6. in slave nodes run start-all.cmd. all the following should appear
   6116 DataNode
   2408 Jps
   3208 NodeManager

note the reason that nameode and resource manager isn't appearing, is becuase they are running on master node and already occupy the port, and you only need the master resourcemanger and name node running

note if you saw multi-cluster tutorial of linux the master node also shows SeceondryNameNode when executing jps. not really sure why its not appearing in windows.

7. go to master:50070, and navigate to data nodes you should see something like this
   [image: Datanode]

8. go to master:8088, and navigate to Node you should see something like this
   [image: resourceManager]

Comment: Step 6 is the main distinction between Window and Ubuntu. In Ubuntu you do not need to run all slave node, you can just run "start-all" on the master node. Thanks for the clarification